Using public key to decrypt RS256 Jwt
I would like to improve my understanding of encryption signing etc.
It is my understanding that the RS256 Jwt is in PKCS1.5 format.
This means they take the days they want to show authenticity about by hashing it with sha256 and then encrypting it with the issuers private key.
Now I think I can do the inverse of this.
I can use the public key to decrypt the content. This will give me the content as the hash that was encrypted.
I'm trying to understand if padding needs to be verified and if so with what value.
I've seen some people say padding in the decrypted PLCS1 FORMAT should be 0xff for the pseudorandom bytes.
So am I thinking correctly?
I tried online searches and various forums.

No, a jwt typically consists of 3 parts, separated by dots. The first and the second part are only base64 encoded json objects. They are not encrypted. The third part is the signature of the two others parts, signed with whatever algorithm is defined in the header.

There are two paddings that are often called PKCS#1 v1.5 padding; one for encryption (with a public key) and one for signing (with a private key). They have been defined in ...(wait for it) ... PKCS#1.
